# How to make plane to follow path?

Tags: modifiers, path

I'm trying to make a long plane or similar to follow path, but the result does not look like I expected. Only the middle face is following path.

[image]

My idea is of course to have the full plane to follow the path. Any ideas from where I should try to looking for the solution? I wonder shall I try to use cloths modifier somehow.

Comment: I suspect you want the plane to deform along the curve. If so, you will get the desired result if you use a Curve Modifier instead of a Follow Path constraint (which i amuse u used.)

Comment: As Fjoersteller says your question is not clear, do you want to create an animation (Follow Path) or do you want your object to be deformed along the curve (Array + Curve modifiers)?

Comment: Yes, I would like to get that the whole plane is along the path. Both of you are correct, I should turn the plane 90 degrees, perhaps that could be then a bit more describing.
Moonboots, I do not want to use array, the parts should be together as scarf which is landing in spiral.

But thanks to both of you, I'll try curve modifier.

Comment: You can use an Array for that. If you click the check box next to Merge in the Array modifier, the object(s) will behave as one. (sorry for the a little bit late response)  : )

Comment: Hi there, back on this. It looks that curve modifier does not work if there is a loop or if there are all three axels involved to curve. At least I have not success to get this work.